# The /health endpoint of my Spring Boot app is emitting all info about the Consul server running on the same machine. How to disable this?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-consul

I've the /health endpoint enabled, but I just don't want it to list all services monitored by Consul on the same machine.

This is my application.properties:

```
# Enable just the health endpoint.
endpoints.health.enabled=true

# Disable all default endpoints and Spring Cloud endpoints.
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.consul.enabled=false
endpoints.pause.enabled=false
endpoints.resume.enabled=false
endpoints.refresh.enabled=false
endpoints.restart.enabled=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=false
endpoints.env.enabled=false

management.health.db.enabled=false
management.health.diskspace.enabled=false
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
```

... and this is what /health is currently emitting:

```
$ curl -o- http://localhost:8080/health | python -m json.tool
{
    "consul": {
        "advertiseAddress": "10.10.10.10", 
        "bindAddress": "10.10.10.10", 
        "clientAddress": "127.0.0.1", 
        "datacenter": "DC", 
        "domain": "consul.", 
        "nodeName": "mynode", 
        "services": {
            "myservice1": [
                "tag1"
            ], 
            "myservice2": [
                "tag1", 
                "tag2"
            ]
        }, 
        "status": "UP"
    }, 
    "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client", 
    "discoveryComposite": {
        "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client", 
        "discoveryClient": {
            "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client", 
            "services": [
                "myservice1",
                "myservice2"
            ], 
            "status": "UP"
        }, 
        "status": "UP"
    }, 
    "status": "UP"
}
```

I don't mind the `"description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client"` but the rest of the stuff under `"consul"` and `"discoveryComposite"` is something I don't want to expose for `/health`.

What could be adding these info here to this endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question for anyone else who might be seeing the same issue: `management.security.enabled=false` was being set in one of the Spring profiles during application startup that I didn't notice. According to the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-health-access-restrictions I need to set `endpoints.health.sensitive=true` to report just the status. Adding this token fixed the issue.

Answer (score 14):

It comes from Spring Cloud Commons.

To disable `discoveryComposite` set property `spring.cloud.discovery.client.composite-indicator.enabled=false`.

Set `management.health.consul.enabled=false` for the other.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb, `spring.cloud.discovery.client.composite-indicator.enabled=false` turned off `discoveryComposite` but surprisingly `management.health.consul.enabled=false` isn't turning off the `"consul": {}` section in `/health`.

Comment: It may be in a later verison of spring cloud consul. What version are you using?

Comment: An update on this: `management.security.enabled=false` was being set in one of the Spring profiles during application startup that I didn't notice. According to the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-health-access-restrictions I need to set `endpoints.health.sensitive=true` to report just the status. Adding this token fixed the issue.

Comment: > but surprisingly `management.health.consul.enabled=false` isn't turning off the "consul": {} section in `/health`.  It is actually disabled by adding config param into `bootstrap.xml`

Answer (score 3):

## Disabling the composite output in SpringBoot 2.3.x

- Just use the following key:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        composite-indicator:
          enabled: false
```

- After that, the output of the discovery was not printed in the status of the healthcheck

Comment: Is it going to impact any functionality or just the actuator reporting of /health?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setting either `spring.cloud.discovery.client.health-indicator.enabled: false` or `spring.cloud.discovery.client.composite-indicator.enabled: false` worked